# Why is $L_A$ not $\mathbb K$ linear (I can prove that it is)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbb K$ denote the skew field of quaternions and $A \in M^{n \times n}(\mathbb K)$ and $X\in M^{1\times n}(\mathbb K)$. Let $L_A : \mathbb K^n \to \mathbb K^n$ be defined as $L_A(X) = (AX^T)^T$.

$L_A$ is supposedly not $\mathbb K$ linear. But I can prove that it is. Like so:

$$ \begin{align}L_A(aX + bY) &= (A(aX + bY)^T)^T =(A(aX^T + bY^T))^T\\
&=(aX^T + bY^T)^TA^T = (aX + bY)A^T \\
&= aXA^T + bYA^T = a(AX^T)^T + b(AY^T)^T \\
&= aL_A(X) + bL_A(Y)
\end{align}$$

Why is this proof wrong?

Comment: Consider the dimensions of $A$ and the dimensions of $X$.

Comment: I assume $A$ here is meant to be an $n\times n $ matrix with entries from $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I am sorry for not stating it. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is noncommutativity. $(aX)^T=X^Ta,$ not $aX^T$-consider the case $n=1$ to clarify this. So you should get $L_A(aX+bY)=L_AX a+L_AYb$, which is certainly a useful relation but not quite linearity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And just to be clear (assuming $a$ is a quaternion): It really is $(aX)^T=X^Ta$ and not $(aX)^T=X^T\overline{a}$?