# Question about transpose of quaternion matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a matrix with entries in the quaternions and $q$ is a quaternion is

$(qA)^T = q A^T$ or $(qA)^T = \overline{q}A^T$?

Comment: probably the first one if it goes the same way as it does in the complex numbers (put the scalar in swap the entries and pull it out again should work imo). If the first (or the second) : $(qA)^T = (qId A)^T = A$

Comment: @user159543 Maybe you could post the link to your question here?

Comment: the question is: the fist one implies $qA^T=(qA)^T = (qI A)^T = A^T qI$ so $A^T $ would swap with any quaternion. Is the problem that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ isn't true in the quaternions?

Comment: @user I've made an edit in my answer, saying your statement is indeed not true if your entries are quaternions.

Comment: The question is unnatural (unless $q$ is central, i.e., real), since multiplying a matrix by a non-central scalar represents nothing. The matrix in itself represents a linear operator, the scalar by itself represents scalar multiplication of vectors by it, which is _not linear_. You can combine the two operations; they even commute by the definition of linearity. However there composite is not a linear operator and therefore cannot be represented by a matrix. Of course you can multiply all matrix entries by a same scalar (either from left or right) but for linear algebra this is meaningless.

Comment: Also note that transposition is not a natural operation unless you interpret the resulting entries in the opposite ring of the quaternions (the quaternions, but with left-right reversed multiplications). This is because you want to have $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$, but you cannot have that unless you interpret transposes over the opposite quaternions. As a consequence it is unclear what kind of multiplication you even mean in $qA^T$; the entries of $A^T$ do not live in the same ring as $q$ does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly define an operator $A^t_{ij} = A_{ji}$, but you probably want the conjugate transpose: $A^\dagger_{ij} = \bar{A}_{ji}$. The point is that $A^\dagger$ should be the transpose of $A$ with respect to the inner product on the space of quaternions, which is $\langle{x,y}\rangle = x\bar{y}$, not $xy$. (The latter is not positive-definite.) The operator $A^\dagger$ satisfies $\langle Ax, y\rangle = \langle x, A^\dagger y\rangle$; the operator $A^t$ does not.

Comment: It's from a book about matrix groups for undergraduates but the author never mentions conjugate transpose. Do you think it is possible the author uses $^T$ to mean conjugate transpose?

Comment: Sure, it's possible. The conjugate transpose is sometimes denoted $A^t, A^\dagger,$ or $A^*$. (There are probably a few others as well.) There's usually no reason to consider $A^t = A_{ji}$, since it's not actually a transpose.

Comment: Great, this seems to solve my problem. I wasn't aware that $^T$ could be used to mean conjugate transpose.

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests that one is interested in inner products. However conjugation is an anti-automorphism of the quaternions, therefore an isomorphism from the opposite quaternions to quaternions. Combining the two operations into $\dagger$ therefore at least has the merit of satisfying $(AB)^\dagger=B^\dagger A^\dagger$ as matrix product _over the quaternions_ (rather than their opposite).

Comment: Actually, could it be that $(qA)^T = A^T \overline{q}$? This answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/846208/161650) seems to claim that.

Comment: I think the answer is yes, see at the end of the paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Conjugation.2C_the_norm.2C_and_reciprocal).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a normal transpose it is $(qA)^T=qA^T$. If you are using a conjugate transpose (=Hermitian transpose) then it is $(qA)^H=\overline{q}A^H$.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) for conjugate transpose.

---

On your follow-up question in the comments: $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ doesn't hold if the entries of your matrix don't live in a commutative ring. So no, it does not hold in the quaternion case.
For example $$\left(\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}j&k\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\right)^T=\begin{pmatrix}k&-j\\0&0\end{pmatrix}^T=\begin{pmatrix}k&0\\-j&0\end{pmatrix}$$ But $$\begin{pmatrix}j&k\\0&0\end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}^T=\begin{pmatrix}j&0\\k&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-k&0\\j&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Good point, thanks for pointing out the thing with the transpose of matrices.

Comment: To clarify, the conjugate transpose does satisfy $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$, since $\langle{ABx, y}\rangle = \langle{Bx, A^\dagger y}\rangle = \langle{x, B^\dagger A^\dagger y}\rangle$ for all $x, y\in \mathbb{H}^n$.